# fullpage.js responsive-slides extension question

Tags: fullpage.js, samsung-galaxy

I'm experimenting with fullPage.js Responsive Slides Extension.
See https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/responsive-slides.html.
Wondering about responsive behavior on my phone: Samsung Galaxy S6.
On this phone, I don't see the site switch to its intended mobile appearance. Specifically, the horizontal rows aren't automatically switching to a completely vertical experience, and the elements aren't resizing.
I do see that site respond accurately using Developer Tools in Chrome and other browsers.
What's up do you think? Or how would you figure out what the issue is? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the site is not using the `viewport` meta tag and therefore the pixels are not the real phone ones.

You can use the following meta tag and see how it works as expected:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```